# Spring security How to define custom role name

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have found some solutions but none of them worked for me. Below code gives

```
"Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [admin]"
```

error. When I change auto-config attribute to "true", again gives same error.

```
<http auto-config="false">
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/login.xhtml*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="admin" />
    <form-login login-page='/pages/login.xhtml' default-target-url="/**"
                authentication-failure-url="/pages/login.xhtml"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/pages/logout.xhtml" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
    <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value=""/>
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide your own *decision manager* (e.g. `org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased`) with your custom configured decision voters via `access-decision-manager-ref="decisionMangerId"` attribute.

But be aware that having no prefix in role voter is not a good idea as it will just try to interpret all security attributes as roles. I strongly recommend to use some prefix, if not the default `ROLE_`.

Or you can enable expression based parsing via `use-expressions="true"` and use `access="hasRole('admin')"` expresion. When going this way, you will also need to change your `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` condition with `access="permitAll"`.

Comment: With the last way, you also need to replace `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` by `permitAll` in my opinion!

Answer (score 3):

It should read:

```
access="hasRole('admin')"
```